# How to apply bold style in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make an editor by myself the first step is to add the Bold style. but I don't understand how to do it. I use the bold() method but it doesn't work.

thanks in advance.

**html**

```
<div class="content">
  <!-- toolbar -->
  <div class="toolbar-content">
    <!-- bold -->
    <span (click)="addBoldStyle()">
      <mat-icon>format_bold</mat-icon>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- textarea -->
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="textarea">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 470px;">
      <mat-label>textarea</mat-label>
      <textarea #text matInput formControlName="editor" rows="5" style="border-radius: 5px"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

**ts.file**

```
  @ViewChild('text') public textarea: ElementRef;

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      editor: null,
    });
  }

  addBoldStyle() {
    console.log('bold');
    this.textarea.nativeElement.innerHTML.bold();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS:

**html**

```
<div class="content">
  <!-- toolbar -->
  <div class="toolbar-content">
    <!-- bold -->
    <span (click)="addBoldStyle()">
      <mat-icon>format_bold</mat-icon>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- textarea -->
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="textarea">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 470px;">
      <mat-label>textarea</mat-label>
      <textarea #text matInput formControlName="editor" rows="5" style="border-radius: 5px"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

**ts.file**

```
  @ViewChild('text') public textarea: ElementRef;

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      editor: null,
    });
  }

  addBoldStyle() {
    console.log('bold');
    this.textarea.nativeElement.style.fontWeight = "bold"
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your quick and clear answer

Comment: by doing this don't add a bold or strong tag so when I console.log my value it displays as if there was no style added

Comment: @foo42 you can add a bold class instead and style that class bold with CSS